# react show png image with transparent style background

Tags: css, reactjs

When I set image:

```
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(exampl.com/image.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

It is white background. Is it possible to show the background with grey and white squares? Thank you
[image]

Comment: Your image is a transparent PNG so it won't have any background. The grey and white squares are the default background of transparent PNG but it can't be seen when you use the picture

Comment: Sometimes I have white images and therefore I wanted to show such background.

Comment: probably somehow with 
`background-image: linear-gradient(
45deg
,#efefef 25%,rgba(239,239,239,0) 25%,rgba(239,239,239,0) 75%,#efefef 75%,#efefef),linear-gradient(
45deg
,#efefef 25%,rgba(239,239,239,0) 25%,rgba(239,239,239,0) 75%,#efefef 75%,#efefef);`

Comment: But it doesn't works

Comment: you have to color the parent div of the image with ```background-color``` or to add a background to the image with a software like Photoshop or an online tool

Comment: the transparent part (gray and white blocks) are not FREE. they are visual effect which is not implemented by css `background`. If you really want to show it, just take a screenshot of current image, bake the "transparency" in and then display it.

Comment: @windmaomao  in google search it somehow calculates and put background with white and grey. Any idea how?

Comment: @jasurbek, that's because Browser does support that :) but that doesn't mean css `background` does that. Also transparency is designed to leak the things below, so it's not designed for background picture, it's designed for next layer :)

Comment: @windmaomao sorry, couldn't get the point. but thank you for the idea with the screenshot, I will try it.

Comment: @windmaomao Also, If you have time, could you please check. Context value doesn't update inside a function, but updates in ComponenDidUpdate. Thank you. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67603987/context-value-not-updated-inside-recompose-withhandlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to another StackOverflow question perfectly solved my problem. [How to create a responsive checkerboard background in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455177/how-to-create-a-responsive-checkerboard-background-in-css)
Thanks to @Peter Krebs for giving a reference.